# Can I use webjars in IntelliJ without building the project?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, frontend, webjars

Is it possible to reference webjar dependencies during compile time in IntelliJ? Imagine I'm playing with some CSS or HTML and making some little adjustments.. I don't want to clean -> rebuild project each time I change font-size or color or etc. I just want to preview them on the fly, in IntelliJ.

Comment: There may be build automatically option.

Comment: This is no betterment.. project is big, so.. each time build the new project is not an option. I want to refresh-preview the page instantaneously.

Comment: No such support for webjars yet, you can follow the [WEB-11226](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11226) [WEB-9621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `webjars` Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>${jquery.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You could refer to your resources by putting the following code in your templates within `<head></head>`:

```
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
            th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"
            th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
```

Attributes `href` and `src` will be used in compile time, while attributes `th:href` and `th:scr` would be used by Thymeleaf in run time.

In the same way you could use your own stylesheets or scripts:

```
<link href="../../static/css/app.css" th:href="@{css/app.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
<script src="../../static/js/app.js" th:src="@{js/app.js}"></script>
```